# Attempting to loop through files with Q.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, q

I am attempting to use `Q.js` to handle some issues with `promises` and `deferrable` in a web application - I will start off by saying my understanding of `async` is basically 0 right now. This is the first time I've truly tried it, and I am **really** lost even after reading as much of the documentation as I can.

I was **previously** using a library called **`jsdeferred`** to accomplish the following code; It loops through a list of files and loads them, and adds them to an array. But I have since learned that I *should not use `jsdeferred`* and I was told I should instead use *`promises`* and *`deferrables`* correctly.

I have explored a lot of venues for this and I may just be stupid, but I am having a very difficult time implementing this exact code in a promises oriented library (in this example, I am trying to use `Q.js`, with no success).

## [Q.js Library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

```
define(function () {
    return function (selector, callback) {  
        var files = [
            "/app_content/json/ecma5.json",
            "/app_content/json/jquery.json",
            "/app_content/json/tangent.json"
        ];
        var results = [];
        var editor, server;

        return Deferred.loop(files.length, function (i) {
            return $.get(files[i]).next(function(data) {
                results.push(data);
            });
        }).next(function () {
            // a lot of things happen here. they are amazing things.
        }).next(function() {
            // seriously, this stuff is awesome.
        }).next(function() {
            callback(editor);
        });
    };
});
```

I'm specifically having a really difficult time with the file loading/looping, any help would be appreciated. I think once I get my footing here, I'll be able to proceed a lot better, but this file looping is really throwing me off. Everything I keep reading in the documentation seems to be for one-time use scenarios.

I am still reading the documentation, and I will continue to do so, but if anyone can help me get my footing here I would greatly appreciate it. Once I see it working with something of my own, it's easier for me to pick up for other situations. I have about 20 other places where I need to start using this concept, but this is the first one that is giving me a headache.

## Update

I do not **have** to use **`Q.js`**, it is just the one that came most recommended. I am looking at `https://github.com/caolan/async` too if it will solve my problem.

## Further Update

Working more with the docs, I have amalgamated something of a working code, but it still seems to be missing something. I am having trouble passing the `results` as parameters to each `then(fn)`, I have to keep it as an outside variable.

```
var results = [];
var editor, server;

var chain = files.reduce(function (previous, item) {
    return previous.then(function(previousValue) {
        return Q.resolve($.get(item, function(data) {
            results.push(data);
        }));
    });
}, Q.resolve());

chain
    .then(function (results) {
    })
    .then(function (results) {    
       // I can't seem to get results to pass through the 2nd 'next'.        
    })
    .then(function () {
        callback(editor);
    });
```

## FINAL RESULT

With the help of everyone here, I have finally made this code work how I want. This is the end result. This is an implementation of **CodeMirror** using **tern** and custom script definitions.

```
define(function () {
    return function (selector, callback) {  
        var editor, server, results, files = [
            "/app_content/json/ecma5.json",
            "/app_content/json/jquery.json",
            "/app_content/json/tangent.json"
        ];

        Q
            .all(files.map($.get))
            .then(function(data) {
                results = data;
            })
            .then(function() {
                editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(selector[0], {
                    mode: { name: "javascript", globalVars: true },
                    lineNumbers: true,
                    lineWrapping: true,
                    matchBrackets: true,
                    indentUnit: 2,
                    tabMode: "spaces",
                    autoCloseBrackets: true,
                    matchTags: true,
                    highlightSelectionMatches: true,
                    continueComments: "Enter",
                    foldGutter: true,
                    width: "100%",
                    gutters: ["CodeMirror-linenumbers", "CodeMirror-foldgutter"],
                    extraKeys: {
                        "Ctrl-Space": "autocomplete",
                        "Ctrl-Q": function(cm) { cm.foldCode(cm.getCursor()); }
                    }
                });
            })
            .then(function() {
                server = new CodeMirror.TernServer({
                    defs: results
                });
                editor.setOption("extraKeys", {
                    "Ctrl-Space": function(cm) { server.complete(cm); },
                    "Ctrl-I": function(cm) { server.showType(cm); },
                    "Alt-.": function(cm) { server.jumpToDef(cm); },
                    "Alt-,": function(cm) { server.jumpBack(cm); },
                    "Ctrl-Q": function(cm) { server.rename(cm); },
                });
                editor.on("cursorActivity", function(cm) { server.updateArgHints(cm); });
            })
            .then(function() {
                callback(editor);
            })
            .done();
    };
});
```

I offer extreme, extreme thanks for the constructive, helpful, useful, and knowledgeable information provided here.

Comment: Wow, so many great answers. I have tried them all and they all work. I need time to think about which one I need to accept as the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Q.js, and assuming that you do not need to send any data along with the request, you could shorten the code using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Q.all`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseall):

```
var results,
    files = [
    "/app_content/json/ecma5.json",
    "/app_content/json/jquery.json",
    "/app_content/json/tangent.json"
];

Q.all(files.map($.get))
    .then(function(_results) {
        results = _results;
    })
    .then(function  () {
        // More awesome stuff here
    })
    .then(function () {
        // etc...
        console.log(results);
    })
    .done();
```

Note that in order to use `results` inside subsequent `.then()` blocks, you must save off a reference to it outside of the promise chain. In your example, the `results` that you wanted was local to the function you passed in to `then()` - it shadowed the global `results`. Simply give it a different name, like `_results`, and then assign it to the global `results` in order to be able to use it later.

Comment: I absolutely love this solution, it is clean, elegant, and easy to read. I really love code that is easy to read. I have a few questions if you're willing to lend your time - I notice one of your lines has `then(function = () {` but the others are just `.then(function(){`. Does the `=` here present anything significant, or is that just the result of typing too fast or without thinking?

Comment: Also, you call `.done();` as an empty method. Does the `done()` method implicitly tell `Q` that the entire 'chain' is finished and it can be concluded? I ask because I have situations where I need to break up a chain between two files. Is this something that can be done using commands like that? I'll make another question for it, so you can get appropriate credit if you have an answer for that.

Comment: @Ciel, the extra `=` in `then(function = () {` was a typo, it shouldn't have been there (I edited the post). And yes, calling `.done()` signals that this promise chain is complete. The [golden rule of then vs done](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisedoneonfulfilled-onrejected-onprogress) is either return your promise to someone else, or terminate it using `done`. Otherwise, unhandled rejections will get silently swallowed up.

Comment: Taking what I learned here, I made a new solution to another problem, you can see the answer here - I have left the question open in case someone sees it and sees an easier way to accomplish it, but I am kind of proud of it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352165/using-q-js-broken-between-two-files-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
function readFile(file) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    $.get(file, function(data) {
         deferred.resolve(data);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

var promises = [];

var files = [
    "/app_content/json/ecma5.json",
    "/app_content/json/jquery.json",
    "/app_content/json/tangent.json"
];

for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    promises.push(readFile(files[i]));
}

Q.all(promises).spread(function(result1, result2, result3) {
    console.log(result1, result2, result3);
});
```

Comment: Hey @Exception, I want to make it clear to you that this worked too. I had a hard time deciding which person to award the answer to. Thank you very much. This is extremely useful.

Comment: @Ciel Don't mind whose answer you have accepted, what only matters to me is whether my answer was helpful or not :)

Comment: It was very useful, indeed. Taking what I learned here, I made a new solution to another problem, you can see the answer here - I have left the question open in case someone sees it and sees an easier way to accomplish it, but I am kind of proud of it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24352165/using-q-js-broken-between-two-files-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: @Ciel That's cool. Have you checked Async.js? It is more matured and provides handful of API methods that makes your coding exciting and easier. Try it, you will love it.

Answer (score 1):

I’m most familiar with [the `async` library](https://github.com/caolan/async) you mentioned, so I’ll show how to use that. Refer to other answers for Q.

The overall structure of your code is that you want to do things serially: one after another. So:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) {
        // do something
    },
    function(callback) {
        // do something else
    },
    function(callback) {
        // and something else still
    }
], function(err) {
    // if err is set, an error occurred somewhere in the series
    // otherwise, all the above functions completed
});
```

So that’ll be the overall structure. Now, what about that loading-each-file thing? Essentially, you want to map from file names to file contents, and `async` makes it easy to map asynchronously:

```
async.map(files, function(file, callback) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: file,
        success: function(data) { return callback(null, data); },
        failure: function(err)  { return callback(err);        }
    });
}, function(err, fileData) {
    // if err is set, an error occurred while fetching one of the files
    // otherwise, fileData is an array with the file data
});
```

You can, of course, nest this `async.map` call inside any of the functions passed to `async.series`, and that’s how you compose the little pieces, building them up until you’ve completed the whole workflow.

Comment: This is really awesome, the `async` library looks totally cool. Does it deal with `Deferrable` and such too? Or is `async` designed to work on a different principle more like `jsdeferred`? I have looked over the site, but I'd love to hear the account of a real user of the library first hand.

Comment: @Ciel: It doesn’t work with promises, no. Traditionally in JavaScript, you just call a function, passing it a callback for it to call when it’s done. Promises are a newer invention, sort of reifying ‘future results’, that can then be returned and passed around and such. The `async` library is designed to work in that traditional callback style, whereas Q is designed to work with souped-up promises. Since most things still use the callback style, I find `async` more convenient, and, (whether it is grounded in fact or not), it just feels more lightweight.

Comment: @Ciel: The two styles can, of course interoperate: you call `then` on a promise, passing it a callback, facilitating callback-style code using promise-style code, and Q provides facilities for wrapping callback-style functions into promise-style functions.